# Python 2.7:About the EAGAIN and EINTR exceptions on socket in CentOS/RedHat 7.2

Tags: python, sockets, centos, redhat

I use python to send files to a server,the code as follow:

```
import socket
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("10.10.10.1",8080))
try:
    sock.send("this is the information")
except:
   #what should I do here to promise that the message is send to server completely without repetitive information
```

My question is that if the EAGAIN or EINTR exception occours when running the "sock.send()",the message I want to send is partly sent to the server or not(or even nothing is sent to the server)?If just a part of the message is sent to the server,how could I know how many bytes are sent and how to send the rest part of the message to the server?Thanks

Comment: Use `.sendall()` instead of `.send()`, and Python will automatically resume the send after interruptions.

Comment: if I use non-block socket,does sendall work?